# Index when mean is constant

Tags: matlab, statistics, mean

I am relatively new to matlab. I found the consecutive mean of a set of 1E6 random numbers that has mean and standard deviation. Initially the calculated mean fluctuate and then converges to a certain value. 
 I will like to know the index (i.e 100th position) at which the mean converges. I have no idea how to do that.

I tried using the logical operator but i have to go through 1e6 data points. Even with that i still can't find the index.

```matlab
Y_c= sigma_c * randn(n_r, 1) + mu_c; %Random number creation

Y_f=sigma_f * randn(n_r, 1) + mu_f;%Random number creation

P_u=gamma*(B*B)/2.*N_gamma+q*B.*N_q + Y_c*B.*N_c; %Calculation of Ultimate load

prog_mu=cumsum(P_u)./cumsum(ones(size(P_u))); %Progressive Cumulative Mean of system response

logical(diff(prog_mu==0)); %Find index
```

Comment: There isn't a specific index at which the mean "converges". Convergence is a limit process; it occurs gradually, and is never fully achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that the mean will never truly be constant, but will rather fluctuate around the "true mean". As such, you'll most likely never encounter a situation where the two consecutive values of the cumulative mean are identical. What you should do is determine some threshold value, below which you consider fluctuations in the mean to be approximately equal to zero, and compare the difference of the cumulative mean to that value. For instance:

```matlab
epsilon = 0.01;
const_ind = find(abs(diff(prog_mu))<epsilon,1,'first');
```

where epsilon will be the threshold value you choose. The `find` command will return the index at which the variation in the cumulative mean first drops below this threshold value.

**EDIT**: As was pointed out, this method may potentially fail if the first few random numbers are generated such that the difference between them is less than the epsilon value, but have not yet converged. I would like to suggest a different approach, then.

We calculate the cumulative means, as before, like so:

```
prog_mu=cumsum(P_u)./cumsum(ones(size(P_u)));
```

We also calculate the difference in these cumulative means, as before:

```
df_prog_mu = diff(prog_mu);
```

Now, to ensure that conversion has been achieved, we find the first index where the cumulative mean is below the threshold value `epsilon` **and** all subsequent means are also below the threshold value. To phrase this another way, we want to find the index after the *last* position in the array where the cumulative mean is *above* the threshold:

```
conv_index = find(~df_prog_mu,1,'last')+1;
```

In doing so, we guarantee that the value at the index, and all subsequent values, have converged below your predetermined threshold value.

Comment: Thanks. I still can't seem to understand how the find function works. I looked at the help for find on matlab and still couldn't figure it out. The '1' signifies what in the find expression please?

Comment: If you pass a logical matrix to the `find` command, it will return the indices of all of the elements that are true. The second argument to `find` allows you to restrict the number of indices that are returned, so in the example above the `1` indicates that it will return only the first element in the matrix that is true (i.e., the first element for which the difference in the cumulative mean is less than your threshold value). The `'first'` tells `find` to return the index of first true value (as opposed to `'last'`, which would return the index of the lat true value.

Comment: I like the answer much better now, though I must admit that I hadn’t noticed the `diff` in there, which does change things. Nonetheless, I would still prefer doing something like `df_prog_mu = prog_mu - prog_mu(end)`, assuming the last mean is the most precise. I think that’s just personal preference... :)

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't imagine that the mean would suddenly become constant at a single index. Wouldn't it asymptotically approach a constant value? I would reccommend a for loop to calculate the mean (it sounds like maybe you've already done this part?) like this:

```
avg = [];
for k=1:length(x)
avg(k) = mean(x(1:k));
end
```

Then plot the consecutive mean:

```
plot(avg)

hold on % this will allow us to plot more data on the same figure later
```

If you're trying to find the point at which the consecutive mean comes within a certain range of the true mean, try this:

```
Tavg = 5; % or whatever your true mean is
err = 0.01; % the range you want the consecutive mean to reach before we say that it "became constant"

inRange = avg>(Tavg-err) & avg<(Tavg+err); % gives you a binary logical array telling you which values fell within the range

q = 1000; % set this as high as you can while still getting a value for consIndex
constIndex = [];

for k=1:length(inRange)
if(inRange(k) == sum(inRange(k:k+q))/(q-1);)
constIndex = k;
end
end
```

The below answer takes a similar approach but makes an unsafe assumption that the first value to fall within the range is the value where the function starts to converge. Any value could randomly fall within that range. We need to make sure that the following values also fall within that range. In the above code, you can edit "q" and "err" to optimize your result. I would recommend double checking it by plotting.

```
plot(avg(constIndex), '*')
```

Comment: Thanks Brett. However i got a little confused. I tried running the code to be able to follow the explanation. I got this error.  I created x=1:100; since your initial code didn't give a range for x.                                                                                         Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in stack (line 18)
if(inRange(k) == sum(inRange(k:k+q))/(q-1)); You are right the mean does not becomes constant it rather fluctuates. I have made an edit to my post. I did plot the mean i obtained with the number of realization. Fluctuations initially then converges.

Comment: This is an expensive way to compute the mean of elements `1:k`. OP has code that does the same using `cumsum`. The difference is that the one requires about N*N/2 operations, the other only about N.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  who is OP?

Comment: OP means “original post”, and refers to the question at the top of the page.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check my code (just wrote it off the top of my head). x should be your set of 1mil random numbers. The for loop that's returning an error should go from 1:(length(inRange)-q). Hope this works better!!